# using call and apply for properties?

Tags: javascript, properties, this

Let's say I have a variable like this:

```
var a = this.property || this.parent.anotherProperty;
```

It's possible to set the context (by context i mean 'this', maybe the 'scope' is a better word...) for `a` like when using `.call()` or `.apply()` for functions?

**EDIT:**

I have an helper function that given a value return:

- if the value is a function -> value()
- if it isn't a function -> value

This is the code:

```
function unwrapValue(value){
   return typeof value === 'function' ? value() : value; 
}
```

unwrapValue is inside a plain object (Utils) and it's called from outside this object:

```
Utils.unwrapValue(value);
```

Now, I have a property `url` in a function (that may be either a function or something else):

```
this.url = this.baseUrl || this.collection.baseUrl;
```

I don't know if this.url is a function or something else so I use unwrapValue to get the value of url:

```
var params = {};
params.url = Utils.unwrapValue(this.url);
```

And the problem is here, unwrapValue return this.url but setting 'this' to something else (i tought it was the Utils object but for some reason it's the `window` object) so `params.url` is `window.baseUrl || window.collection.baseUrl` which is not what i want.

If `value` is a function I solved this way:

```
function unwrapValue(value, context){
    if(typeof value === 'function'){
        return typeof context === 'undefined' ? value() : value.call(context);
    }else{
        return value;
    }
}
```

so that if a second parameter `context` is passed to `unwrapValue`, value's `this` will be set to `context`.

with this question I was searching a way to use `context` aslo in the case `value` wasn't a function like:

```
this.url = this.baseUrl || this.collection.url;
```

And just to clarify a little more: this.baseUrl and this.collection.url are simple strings

There's a way to solve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "set the context"?

Comment: confusing.  You have three `a`'s - one is a variable, not a property.  one is a property of `this`, and one a property of `this.parent`.

Comment: The first argument to `call` or `apply` is the function context.

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with scopes. I still have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: updated, but more or less is what @Bergi answered but I want to achieve that without wrapping 'a' into a function.

Comment: @melpomene i mean the function context (the value of 'this') that you can set passing it to the first argument of call/apply

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi Uh... like `var a = someObject.a`? Why do you have to use `this` if you want to use some other object anyway?

Comment: because i need that in an helper function where either a and the context I want to set may change every time i use that helper function

Comment: I feel like I'm in the twilight zone.

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi You're not making any sense.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that makes it much clearer. Though: There is no context for non-function values (primitives, objects). The concept of a value acting as a "context" applies only when a *function is called*, for example `this` being the context in `this.baseUrl()` or `this.collection` being the context of `this.collection.url()`.

Comment: I've found something similar to my unwrapValue in underscore.js http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html, i think their implementation is just perfect for what i want to do, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possibly want to pass an object literal as the *thisArg* into that function:

```
function fn() {
    var a = this.a || this.parent.a;
    console.log(a);
}
fn.call({
    a: false,
    parent: {
        a: "foobar"
    }
});
```

As you don't pass in further arguments, you could've used [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) as well instead of [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: exactly, but there's a way that doesn't need encapsulating a in a function?

Comment: What do you mean? The [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) only makes sense inside a function (in the most cases), and you need a function to invoke `call`/`apply` on it.

Comment: i'd like to evaluate the value of the var 'a' setting 'this' like when using a function.

Comment: You cannot set `this` (ie. assign to it), it is non-writable. Of course you could set properties on it (as long as it is an object)

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi: Variables don't work that way.  You can't change a variable's "context", like you can a function's.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Exactly. …because a variable has no "context".

Comment: but that variable is not a string is an 'evaluation' like var a = function(){ return this.property || this.parent.anotherProperty }

Comment: I still don't get what you want to do.  Pretty sure you can't do it.

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi: I don't think you mean that function expression literally, do you? I guess by "evaluation" you mean [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators), which is part of an assignment [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) in here

Comment: exactly, ok it seems that this isn't possible

Comment: What are you trying to do? Creating a getter function for a variable?

Comment: I've updated the question, probably I haven't been very clear explaining my problem, sorry but I'm not of english mother tongue

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `a` is a function (it's unclear from your question) then you can use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the context for all calls made to it:

```
var a = (this.a || this.parent.a).bind(this);
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more information and a shim for older browsers.

Comment: Note that `bind` is non-standard. It needs shimming in IE8.

Comment: `.bind` is standard in ES5 and available in all latest-release mainstream browsers.

Comment: It still needs shimming in IE8.

Comment: IE8 doesn't just need shimming, it needs consigning to the dark ages ;-)

Comment: At least IE7's dead, and with it CSS hacks / conditional HTML. We're still stuck with CSS2 and shimming.

Comment: please see the Edit I made